# Laravel: how to check if array is empty or not?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

let's say i have this query:

```
 $schedules = [33,34];
 foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
     $buses[] = DB::table("buses")->select('id', 'bus_number')
                      ->where('station_id', $stations_id)
                      ->whereNotNull('Driver_id')
                      ->get();
 }
```

The data it is returning is empty like this:   `[[],[]]`

So, my question **Is how to check if there is data in it or not?**

Comment: you can assign the result to a variable and check that variable `$count = DB....;if ($count->count())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be excluding null filled values:

```
$schedules = [33,34];
foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
     $bus = DB::table("buses")->select('id', 'bus_number')
                  ->where('station_id', $stations_id)
                  ->whereNotNull('Driver_id')
                  ->get();
     if($bus && isset($bus->id)) {
         $buses[] = $bus;
     }
 }
 if($buses && count($buses)>0) {
     //has value
 }
```

If you have related Schedule with buses, you could use, something like this;

```
$schedules = Schedule::whereIn('id',$schedule_ids)->with('buses')->get();
//and you dont need to set into an array
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it's not helping, it will always it has data even if it's empty

Comment: can you explain the problem a little bit more? what would have data? $buses?

Comment: the above query is returning `[[],[]]`, and obviously, it's not returning any data, so how i do i check if it's empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

You could use count() funcion, something like this:

```
$schedules = [33,34];
foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
   $bus = DB::table("buses")->select('id', 'bus_number')
              ->where('station_id', $stations_id)
              ->whereNotNull('Driver_id')
              ->get();

   if(count($buses) > 0) {
      $buses[] = $bus;
   }
}
```